# Underscore in URL not working with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

The following problem occurs in the Visual Studio 2013 IDE. It seems to work correctly when deployed to IIS.

I have an attribute route that looks like this:

```
    [Route("SiteCode/{sites:alpha?}")]
```

When I request /SiteCode, it works fine. When I include a parameter, such as /SiteCode/something, that too works fine. When the URL is /SiteCode/some_thing, however, it does not find the controller and I get a 404.

This one works with underscores in the SiteCodes parameter:

```
[Route("Performance/{CountryIDs?}/{StateIDs?}/{SiteCodes?}/{Titles?}/{StartDate:datetime?}/{EndDate:datetime?}")]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints `alpha` constraint matches only uppercase and lowercase latin characters and underscore is not one of them.

If you want to allow underscore you can use following constraint:

```
regex(^[a-zA-Z_]+$)
```