# Azure Python Function: Underscore are not working in routes

Tags: python, azure-functions

Hello i am creating an "Azure Python Function" with an POST/GET route in the UNC path like http://localhost:7071/api/indicator/sjz_jb_1. I create therefore the following code :

**function.json**

In the previous version I used `{indicator:alpa?}`  based on https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python#customize-the-http-endpoint. But with the alfa datatype the underscores are not working. After searching on the internet I found the stackoverflow post  [Underscore in URL not working with attribute routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394109/underscore-in-url-not-working-with-attribute-routing) it was based on c# but the code was still working but still result in a page not found.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "indicator/{indicator:regex(^[a-zA-Z_]+$)}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

**init.py**

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func
from shared_code.Metadata import Visualisatieportal_indicatoren


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    ind = req.route_params.get('indicator')  
    logging.info(ind)
    indicator1 = Visualisatieportal_indicatoren.getVisualisatieportal_indicatoren(ind)
    result = json.dumps(indicator1.__dict__)
    return func.HttpResponse(str(id))
```

My question is, what do I need to change so the so underscores can support in the route of the endpoints.

Manny thanks
Erik

Comment: Try this regex `/^\w+$/` where `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!   Should the route then be  "route": "indicator/{indicator:regex(/^\w+$/)?}" ?

Comment: Yes, Give a try!

Comment: That don't work page not found error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what do I need to change so the so underscores can
> support in the route of the endpoints.

One of the workaround could solve the above issue,

To use underscore you can try with the below :

```
 "route": "indicator/{indicator:regex(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$)}"
```

Also Based on this [***`MS DOC`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python#attributes-and-annotations) we can not use following `attribute` in **python function** except **c# & java**.

[image]